# Use jQuery to find an element id that contains a variable

Tags: jquery

I know I can use jQuery to find html elements whose id contains certain text. like below:

```
$("div[id*='uStatus']").first();
```

The above code helps me find all the elements whose ids contain 'uStatus'. However, if the 'uStatus' itself is a variable then it won't work.

I tried the code below, but it returns no result:

```
var name = 'uStatus' + loginName;  
$("div[id*='" + name + "']").first();
```

I am sure the login name is there.  Thanks a lot for your help !

Below is the attached the rendered HTML for reference:

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_peopleList1_gvPeople_uStatusUserB_0"><div style='padding:4px; background-color:#dedede;font-size:11px;'>UserB</div></div>
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_peopleList1_gvPeople_uStatusUserA_1"><div style='padding:4px; background-color:#dedede;font-size:11px;'>UserA</div></div>
```

Comment: Is the typo in `uStaus` only in your question or is it the cause of your problem?

Comment: So does an id containing at minimum:  `name` exist in your working set?  We have nothing to compare against or query against to test.

Comment: Rendered HTML would help.

Comment: To: Frédéric Hamidi: It was a typo for uStatus. Thank you :-) I updated the question. To: Fallenreaper and ragerory: I attached the rendered HTML code for reference. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the single quote from the jQuery selector. Hope this helps.

```
var name = 'uStaus' + loginName;  
$("div[id*=" + name + "]").first();
```

Comment: That would make the situation worse if `loginName` contains spaces or other characters that must be escaped in selectors (e.g. square brackets or dots).